# how to test a hook with async state update in useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-testing-library, react-hooks-testing-library

i have a simple hook that fetches the value and sets it to option as follows:

```js
import Fuse from 'fuse.js'
import React from 'react'

// prefetches options and uses fuzzy search to search on that option
// instead of fetching on each keystroke
export function usePrefetchedOptions<T extends {}>(fetcher: () => Promise<T[]>) {
  const [options, setOptions] = React.useState<T[]>([])
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // fetch options initially
    const optionsFetcher = async () => {
      try {
        const data = await fetcher()
        setOptions(data)
      } catch (err) {
        errorSnack(err)
      }
    }
    optionsFetcher()
  }, [])
  // const fuseOptions = {
  //   isCaseSensitive: false,
  //   keys: ['name'],
  // }

  // const fuse = new Fuse(options, fuseOptions)

  // const dataServiceProxy = (options) => (pattern: string) => {
  //   // console.error('options inside proxy call', { options })
  //   const optionsFromSearch = fuse.search(pattern).map((fuzzyResult) => fuzzyResult.item)
  //   return new Promise((resolve) => resolve(pattern === '' ? options : optionsFromSearch))
  // }

  return options
}
```

i am trying to test it with following code:

```js
import { act, renderHook, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react-hooks'
import { Wrappers } from './test-utils'
import { usePrefetchedOptions } from './usePrefetchedOptions'
import React from 'react'

const setup = ({ fetcher }) => {
  const {
    result: { current },
    waitForNextUpdate,
    ...rest
  } = renderHook(() => usePrefetchedOptions(fetcher), { wrapper: Wrappers })
  return { current, waitForNextUpdate, ...rest }
}

describe('usePrefetchedOptions', () => {
  const mockOptions = [
    {
      value: 'value1',
      text: 'Value one',
    },
    {
      value: 'value2',
      text: 'Value two',
    },
    {
      value: 'value3',
      text: 'Value three',
    },
  ]
  test('searches for appropriate option', async () => {
    const fetcher = jest.fn(() => new Promise((resolve) => resolve(mockOptions)))
    const { rerender, current: options, waitForNextUpdate } = setup({ fetcher })
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(fetcher).toHaveBeenCalled()
    })
    // async waitForNextUpdate()
    expect(options).toHaveLength(3) // returns initial value of empty options = []
  })
})
```

the problem is when i am trying to assert the options at the end of the test, it still has the initial value of `[]`. However if I log the value inside the hook, it returns the mockOptions. How do I update the hook after it is update by useEffect but in async manner.

I have also tried using using `waitForNextUpdate` where it is commented in the code. it times out with following error:
`Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Couple things, currently you're waiting for `fetcher` to be called in your tests, but the state update actually happens not after `fetcher` is called but after the promise that `fetcher` returns is resolved. So you'd need to wait on the resolution of that promise in your test

Also, you're destructuring the value of `result.current` when you first render your hook. That value is just a copy of `result.current` after that first render and it will not update after that. To query the current value of `options`, you should query `result.current` in your assertion instead.

```
const fetcherPromise = Promise.resolve(mockOptions);
const fetch = jest.fn(() => fetcherPromise);
const { result } = renderHook(() => usePrefetchedOptions(fetcher), { wrappers: Wrappers })
await act(() => fetcherPromise);
expect(result.current).toHaveLength(3)
```

Comment: "Also, you're destructuring the value of result.current when you first render your hook.That value is just a copy of result.current after that first render and it will not update after that." This is the answer I was looking for to the question I could not find anywhere on SO. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me whenI needed to test the second effect of my context below:

```js
import React, {createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {IGlobalContext} from "../models";
import {fetchGravatar} from "../services";
import {fetchTokens, Token} from "@mylib/utils";

const GlobalContext = createContext<IGlobalContext>({} as IGlobalContext);


function useGlobalProvider(): IGlobalContext {
    const [token, setToken] = useState<Token>(Token.deserialize(undefined));
    const [gravatar, setGravatar] = useState<string>('');

    useEffect(() => {
        setToken(fetchTokens());
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (token?.getIdToken()?.getUsername()) {
            fetchGravatar(token.getIdToken().getUsername())
                .then(setGravatar)
        }
    }, [token]);

    const getToken = (): Token => token;
    const getGravatar = (): string => gravatar;

    return {
        getToken,
        getGravatar
    }
}

const GlobalProvider: React.FC = ({children}) => {
    const globalContextData: IGlobalContext = useGlobalProvider();
    return (
        <GlobalContext.Provider value={globalContextData}>{children}</GlobalContext.Provider>
    );
};


function useGlobalContext() {
    if (!useContext(GlobalContext)) {
        throw new Error('GlobalContext must be used within a Provider');
    }
    return useContext<IGlobalContext>(GlobalContext);
}

export {GlobalProvider, useGlobalContext};
```

corresponding tests:

```js
import React from "react";
import {GlobalProvider, useGlobalContext} from './Global';
import {act, renderHook} from "@testing-library/react-hooks";
import utils, {IdToken, Token} from "@mylib/utils";
import {getRandomGravatar, getRandomToken} from 'mock/Token';
import * as myService from './services/myService';
import {Builder} from "builder-pattern";
import faker from "faker";


jest.mock('@mylib/utils', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('@mylib/utils')
}));


describe("GlobalContext", () => {
    it("should set Token when context loads", () => {
        const expectedToken = getRandomToken('mytoken');
        const spyFetchToken = spyOn(utils, 'fetchTokens').and.returnValue(expectedToken);

        const wrapper = ({children}: { children?: React.ReactNode }) => <GlobalProvider>{children} </GlobalProvider>;

        const {result} = renderHook(() => useGlobalContext(), {wrapper});

        expect(spyFetchToken).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(result.current.getToken()).toEqual(expectedToken);
    })

    it("should fetch Gravatar When Token username changes", async () => {

        const expectedToken = getRandomToken('mytoken');
        const expectedGravatar = getRandomGravatar();
        const returnedGravatarPromise = Promise.resolve(expectedGravatar);
        const spyFetchToken = spyOn(utils, 'fetchTokens').and.returnValue(expectedToken);
        const spyFetchGravatar = spyOn(myService, 'fetchGravatar').and.returnValue(returnedGravatarPromise);


        const wrapper = ({children}: { children?: React.ReactNode }) =>
            <GlobalProvider>{children} </GlobalProvider>;

        const {result, waitForValueToChange} = renderHook(() => useGlobalContext(), {wrapper});

        // see here
        // we need to wait for the promise to be resolved, even though the gravatar spy  returned it
        let resolvedGravatarPromise;
        act(() => {
            resolvedGravatarPromise = returnedGravatarPromise;
        })

        await waitForValueToChange(() => result.current.getGravatar());

        expect(spyFetchToken).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(result.current.getToken()).toEqual(expectedToken);
        expect(spyFetchGravatar).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expectedToken.getIdToken().getUsername());
        expect(resolvedGravatarPromise).toBeInstanceOf(Promise);
        expect(result.current.getGravatar()).toEqual(expectedGravatar);

    })
})
```